# How to filter an observable?

Tags: angular, rxjs, ng-bootstrap, angular2-observables

I'm using the ngbootstrap typeahead component with firebase.

I'm trying to figure out how to filter the results of an observable based on the firstname of all documents returned.

Running into the error: `[ts] Property 'pipe' does not exist on type 'Promise<any>'. [2339]`

```
async  getAllContacts(term){
    let res = this.contactService.getAllContacts();

    return await res.filter(v => v.firstname.toLowerCase().indexOf(term.toLowerCase()) > -1).slice(0, 10)
  }
  search = (text$: Observable<string>) =>
  text$.pipe(
    debounceTime(300),
    distinctUntilChanged(),
    switchMap(term =>
      this.getAllContacts(term).pipe(
        catchError(() => {
          return of([]);
        }))
    ),
  )
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It seems that you're getting back a Promise, not an Observable.

Answer (score 1):

Change to

```
   switchMap(term =>
      from(this.getAllContacts(term)).pipe(
        catchError(() => {
          return of([]);
        }))
    ),
```

> Update

If `getAllContacts` return observable change the method to below and just remove the from() operator from the above old answer.

```
getAllContacts(term){
    return this.contactService.getAllContacts().pipe(map(res=>
    res.filter(v =>v.firstname.toLowerCase().indexOf(term.toLowerCase()) > -1).slice(0, 10)
))
}
```

Comment: getting this error now: `res.filter is not a function`

Comment: what is the return type of  this.contactService.getAllContacts()

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of problems I see in the code above.  Fan has already pointed out the error in going from a Promise to an Observable, but when this one problem was solved, the next issue cropped up.

This second issue to me looks like you may be mixing rxjs versions in the same code - did you copy and paste it from different locations? res.filter would have invoked the `filter` operator in older rxjs syntax, but with v6+ that syntax has changed and now filter is invoked differently.  `slice` is even older, back to rxjs v4 (now replaced by a combo of skip & take - note in the below code I removed skip since it would be skip(0) which does nothing)

so if `filter` and `slice` are meant to be operators on the resulting Observable, then the rxjs6 version of that will look quite different.

If all that is what is going on then you could change your code to:

```
async getAllContacts(term) {
  let res = this.contactService.getAllContacts();

  return await res.pipe(filter(v => v.firstname.toLowerCase().indexOf(term.toLowerCase()) > -1),take(10))
}
search = (text$: Observable<string>) =>
text$.pipe(
  debounceTime(300),
  distinctUntilChanged(),
  switchMap(term =>
    from(this.getAllContacts(term)).pipe(
      catchError(() => {
        return of([]);
    }))
  ),
)
```

However, that is a real mess of tangled and confusing code I think.  All this leaves me thinking it could be dramatically simplified.

---

Given what you mentioned in the comments below, here is a possible simplification of the above code.  Get rid of the async function which returns a promise and do it all within `search`, something like this:

```
search = (text$: Observable<string>) => text$.pipe(
    debounceTime(300),
    distinctUntilChanged(),
    switchMap(term => this.contactService.getAllContacts().pipe(
        filter(v => v.firstname.toLowerCase().indexOf(term.toLowerCase()) > -1),
        take(10),
        catchError(() => of([]))
    ))
);
```

Comment: I'm using angular fire store and I'm trying to retrieve all the documents and then use a type ahead to filter the results.

Comment: @JustinYoung given that you are trying to implement a filter, I updated my answer with a possible code simplification.